# PSQLException: ERRO: listas de alvos podem ter no máximo 1664 entradas

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Estou tentando persistir um objeto no banco mais recebo este erro:

```
WARN:   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 54000
ERROR:   ERRO: listas de alvos podem ter no máximo 1664 entradas
Advertência:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrdemServicoFacade, method: public void br.com.curso.ejb.OrdemServicoFacade.salvar(br.com.curso.entidade.OrdemServico)
```

Meu Metodo Salvar

```
     @Override
    public void salvar(OrdemServico entity) {

        if (entity.getVenda().equals(false)) {

            entity = em.merge(entity);

        } else if (entity.getTipoDoc().equals("DINHEIRO")) {

            entity = em.merge(entity);

            geraContasReceber(entity);

        } else if (entity.getTipoDoc().equals("CHEQUE")) {
            entity = em.merge(entity);
            geraCheque(entity);
            if (entity.getEntrada().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {

                geraContasRecebidas(entity);

            }

        } else if (entity.getTipoDoc().equals("CARTÃO CRÉDITO")) {
            entity = em.merge(entity);
            geraCartaoCredito(entity);

            if (entity.getEntrada().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {

                geraContasRecebidas(entity);

            }
            //CONTROLE CARTÃO CREDITO
        } else if (entity.getTipoDoc().equals("CARTÃO DÉBITO")) {
            entity = em.merge(entity);
            geraCartaoDebito(entity);
            if (entity.getEntrada().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {

                geraContasRecebidas(entity);

            }
            //CONTROLE CARTÃO DÉBITO

        } else if (entity.getTipoDoc().equals("CREDIÁRIO")) {
            entity = em.merge(entity);
            geraContasReceber(entity);
            if (entity.getEntrada().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {

                geraContasRecebidas(entity);

            }
            //CONTROLE CARTÃO DÉBITO

        }
    }
```

Minha Entidade (Atributos)

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtVenda = new Date();
    @Column
    private String nomeFun;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataVencimento = new Date();
    @Column
    private BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal entrada = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal valorHora = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalDesc = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalDescEn = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalHoras = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal acrescimo = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal desconto = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal valorDesconto = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private Boolean venda = Boolean.FALSE;
    @Column
    private String valida;
    private String recebido;
    private String recebido2;
    private String recebido3;
    @Column
    private String localServico = "INTERNO";
    @ManyToOne
    private Bandeira bandeira;
    @Column
    private String numeroDoc;
    @Column
    private String modelo;
    @Column
    private String veiculo;
    private String contato;
    private String veiculo2;
    private String veiculo3;
    private String placa;
    private String placa2;
    private String placa3;
    private String obsVeiculo;
    @Column(length = 800)
    private String solicitacaoCliente;
    @Column
    @CPF
    private String cpfNota;
    @Column
    private String cnpjNota;
    @Column
    private String numeroSerie;
    @Column
    private String numeroHorasMaquinas;
    @Column
    private String numeroSerieMotor;
    @Column
    private String numeroSerieTranmmissao;
    @Column
    private String tipoServico;
    @Column
    private String saiuDe;
    private String chegouEm;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date horaSaida = new Date();
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date horaChegada = new Date();
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtIn;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtFim;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtPrevisao;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date horaViagem;

    private BigDecimal inicioServico = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column(length = 600)
    private String descricaoProblema;
    @Column(length = 800)
    private String solucaoProblema;
    private BigDecimal terminoServico = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal horaDeTrabalho = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private String idFrota;
    private String kmInicial;
    private String kmFinal;
    @Column
    @Min(value = 1)
    private Integer qtdParcela = 1;
    @Column
    private String tipoPagamento = "A VISTA";
    @Column(length = 600)
    private String obs = "".toUpperCase();
    private String obs2 = "".toUpperCase();
    private String obs3 = "".toUpperCase();
    private String tipoDoc;
    @Column
    private Boolean fiscal = Boolean.FALSE;
    @ManyToOne
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    @ManyToOne
    private Funcionario funcionario;
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoDeManutencao tipoDeManutencao;
    @ManyToOne
    private SituacaoOs situacaoOs;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String xml;
    private Boolean naoTransmitida;
    @ManyToOne
    private Banco banco;
    private String modeloNota;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "ordemServico")
    private List<ItemServico> itensServicos = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "ordemServico")
    private List<ItemEquipamentos> itensEquipamentos = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "ordemServico",
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Parcela> parcelas;
    @ManyToOne
    private Empresa empresa;

    @Column(length = 900)
    private String retornoFiscal;
    @Column
    private String codNfce;
    @Column
    private String chaveNfce;
    @Column
    private String chaveNfe;
    @Column
    private String codNfe;
    @Column
    private Boolean fiscalCancelado;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCancelamentoFiscal;
    @Column
    private String situacaoConsulta;
    @Column
    private String statusAux;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este erro ocorre porque você está retornando muitas colunas ao mesmo tempo e batendo no limite do próprio PostgreSQL.

Este caso é bem típico usando Hibernate quando temos um mapeamento de entidade abusando da estratégia `EAGER`, carregando outras entidades junto com ela a cada consulta da mesma. Isto pode ser corrigido, principalmente, configurando os mapeamentos `@OneToOne` e `@ManyToOne` para `LAZY`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Pessoa pessoa;
```

Na teoria até seria possível aumentar este limite de 1664 no PostgreSQL, mas parece que [não é possível](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20080706000420.4d9409f1%40btj-laptop.asp-as.no#4053f63988da6fc0cbddf339fff82a9d) fazer isto hoje e não seria uma boa recomendação de qualquer forma.

Comment: Sua resposta resolveu meu problema, só uma observação, quando usamos o LAZY em objetos que aparecem em uma lista por exemplo, precisamos carregar ele manualmente, mais se não aparecer na lista e só colocar @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) e tudo certo. Obrigado pela resposta.